# Did Yitzhak become a new Hedwig?

Tags: character, hedwig-and-the-angry-inch

Near the end of *Hedwig and the Angry Inch*, Hedwig removes her wig and hands it to Yitzhak, who eventually realizes that Hedwig wants him to wear (as opposed to wanting Yitzhak to put it back on Hedwig's own head).  Yitzhak dons the wig, spins around, and is transformed from a bearded biker dude into a beautiful blonde Hedwig-esque woman.  Here is the scene in question:

Hedwig then walks off naked, apparently not herself any more - or at least, not her genderqueer, punk/glam rock star former persona.

**I've never been clear on what this meant for Yitzhak and Hedwig:  Is the idea that Yitzhak becomes the new Hedwig, and Hedwig becomes Hansel again?  Or does Yitzhak just become a famous glam rock Yitzhak, and Hedwig becomes a non-rock-star Hedwig?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that was cut from the film was Yitzhak wanting to do drag but Hedwig stopping him, which would better explain the wig and Yitzhak's transformation.

However, the main takeaway from this moment is Hedwig freeing herself from the need of external validations or "definitions" of who she is. This is the reason for removing the feminine clothes and the wig and walking alone. Hedwig is finally whole and at peace with herself, not needing anyone or anything else for completeness.

Comment: Is that a "yes"?

Comment: It's a "yes" in that both characters ultimately get what they want. Hedwig no longer feels the need to present him/herself as anything, where Yitzhak desperately wants to be feminine.